# "Read more" doesn't appear on categories page of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories

"Read more" link appears on index page, while it doesn't on the separate category page. The categories page code is pretty much the same, as on index page.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

entire code of the page

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<div class="container">

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><div class="tabs1"><div id="t1"><div class="bmtxt"><?php
$post_id = 76;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
?>
<p><?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?></p></div>
    </div></div>
    </li>


    <li class="tabs2"><div class="tabs1"> <div id="t2"><div class="bmtxt"><?php
$post_id = 83;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
?>
<p><?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?></p></div>
    </div></div>
    </li>


    <li class="tabs2"><div class="tabs1"><div id="t3"><div class="bmtxt"><?php
$post_id = 92;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
?>
<p><?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?></p></div>
    </div></div>
   </li>


     <li class="tabs2"><div class="tabs1"><div id="t4"><div class="bmtxt"><?php
$post_id = 98;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
?>
<p><?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?></p></div>
    </div></div>
   </li>


</ul>
</div>
</div>


<div class="container-full" id="cnt1">
<div class="container">
<div id="content">
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And a little bit more text to allow the site all of this code

Comment: Please post your index page code as well, you must be missing something.

Comment: Content wise, it's absolutely identical. <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

Comment: Is it possible that the entire article is displayed so Read more does not appear?

Comment: nope. entire article is way longer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) instead of [the_content()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content).

In this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates) Modifying How Posts are Displayed section is useful to you to know about how to display the content.

Also in the code you have provided,

```
echo $queried_post->post_content;
```

is responsible for the content display. I don't know what theme you are using?. So instead of using post_content we have to use post_excerpt.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this under the article code:

```
<?php echo "<form  action='";
echo the_permalink();
echo "' method='get'>";?>
<button>Read More..</button></form>
```

If there is more text it should pick it up

Error found:

```
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post()?>
```

You are missing ";" before ?>

Comment: it added the button, but button it self redirects to index page, and "read more" doesn't cut the post, where i place it.

Comment: OMG I see it: <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post();?> you are missing ";" tell me if that fixes the problem ... :) it would be quite funny :) hehe after all that

Comment: nope. that's not it. Besides, index and categories page code is almost identical (except index having sidebar). Yet it works perfectly on index, and categories is eating my brain out for a while already

Comment: Hmm do you have this up and running online can i see it? and if not can you post whole code from the page that is not working including header, and footer

Comment: Your code is formated so wired in the source, it prints every line in new <p></p> hmm so wired.. Let me look at this for a bit..

Comment: thank you!  btw, I'm using blankslate theme as a framework, if it helps

Comment: I noticed that you have lot of orphan end tags of </p>, you may need to look at that.. Do yo have a firebug or something that checks the code in browser that gives back errors?

Comment: Even when you click your link it displays it wrong, I would suggest creating a single-post template and using it as display. Sorry not much I can do there for you on that. I will see if I can figure out why (more) is not appearing .. it must be rendering error a code is missing somewhere on the page or something is unclosed... On your error page there is 5-6 orphan </div> tags including some </p> look into your set-up there is lot of errors there.. Run it in W3 Validator.

Comment: I tried using the exact same code as index page (with sidebar and bootstrap columns), but it didn't work as well. Thank you for the time

Comment: Go here: http://validator.w3.org/ and add that URL there is 35 errors and 23 warning :(

Comment: orphan p's are probably from this piece of code <li class="tabs2"><div class="tabs1"> <div id="t2"><div class="bmtxt"><?php
$post_id = 83;
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);
?>
<p><?php echo $queried_post->post_content; ?></p></div>
        </div></div>
        </li> I really have no clue why would they be shown as orphans, while clearly having an opening tag. Despite of these errors, i still can't understand why would same piece of code work in page with one name, and not with a different name.

Comment: I don't really understand most of errors in validator as well, since, for the most part, i have a different code in my source file. But, i guess, it's a different story.